# Can a MeteorJS app be instrumented for OpenTelemetry

Tags: meteor, open-telemetry

I'm not familiar with MeteorJS other than it's a framework whose underlying language is Node.js. Having said that, can you instrument an app in MeteorJS for OpenTelemetry?

Comment: Yes, you can. https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/getting-started/nodejs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately at the moment there is no auto-instrumentation for MeteorJS, but you can still use OpenTelemetry to instrument your app manually.

To do the manual instrumentation you can follow this guide:
https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/instrumentation/

And in this registry you can find the list of supported frameworks (which can be used with the auto-instrumentation):
https://opentelemetry.io/registry/?language=js&component=instrumentation